# limit and stationary distribution of a Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Consider a Markov chain on the non-negative integers with transition
probabilities $1/2$ if $y=x+1$ and $1/2$ if $y=0$. Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_{n}=0)$.

Is this limit the same as the stationary distribution? What's the relationship between the two?

Answer (score 1):

Given is the Markov Chain $\{X_n, n\ge1\}$, with its T.P.M described as,

$p_{ij}^{(1)} = P(X_n = j \mid X_{n-1} = i) = \begin{cases}
                                         \frac{1}{2} & \text{if $j = i + 1$}\\
                                         \frac{1}{2} & \text{if $j = 0$}\\
                                         0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

We need to obtain the limiting distribution of the Markov Chain, i.e. $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} p_{ij}^{(n)}$ where $p_{ij}^{(n)}$ is the n-step transition probability.

Consider this,

$p_{ij}^{(n)} = P(X_n = j \mid X_0 = i) = \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}P(X_n = j \mid X_{n-1} = k).P(X_{n-1} = k \mid X_0 = i) ; j \ne 0$

$p_{ij}^{(n)} = \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}p_{kj}^{(1)}.p_{ik}^{(n-1)}
 ; j \ne 0$

But $p_{kj}^{(1)} = \frac{1}{2}$ if $k = j - 1$ and $0$ otherwise, so we get the following recurrence relation,

$p_{ij}^{(n)} = \dfrac{1}{2}.p_{ij-1}^{(n-1)} ; j \ne 0$.

Denote by $p_{ij}$ the limiting probability $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}p_{ij}^{(n)}$. Taking the limits of the above equation, we get

$\begin{align}
\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}p_{ij}^{(n)} = \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{2}.p_{ij-1}^{(n-1)}               \\
p_{ij} = \dfrac{1}{2}.p_{ij-1} = \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^jp_{i0} \tag 1\\
\end{align}$

$\text{ where } p_{i0} = \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n = 0 \mid X_0 = i) \text{ and } j \ne 0$

Again, $P(X_n = 0 \mid X_0 = i) = \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}P(X_n = 0 \mid X_{n-1} = k).P(X_{n-1} = k \mid X_0 = i)$

$p_{i0}^{(n)} = \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}p_{k0}^{(1)}.p_{ik}^{(n-1)}$

But $p_{k0}^{(1)} = \frac{1}{2} \text{ for all } k \text{ and } \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}p_{ik}^{(n-1)} = 1$, we get $p_{i0}^{(n)} = \frac{1}{2}$. And thus,

$p_{i0} = \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}p_{i0}^{(n)} = \dfrac{1}{2}$. Now putting this value in $(1)$, we get,

$p_{ij} = \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{j+1}$.

From this, we notice that the limiting probability $p_{ij}$ is independent of the initial state $i$. And thus all the rows in the corresponding TPM will be identical, making it also the stationary probabilities.